# Mapping one to many with Dapper (Two list with one object)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, api, dapper

I have student object with two list.I want retrieve student list from stored procedure.How can i get student object list with mentioned two list using dapper.

public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

```
public string RefNo { get; set; }

public int StudentModeId { get; set; }

public string FullName { get; set; }

public string KnownName { get; set; }

public List<StudentAttachment> StudentAttachments { get; set; }
public List<StudentExpenses> StudentExpenceses { get; set; }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use something called [QueryMultiple](https://dapper-tutorial.net/querymultiple).

If you're trying to effectively return 2 lists from 1 sproc and then populate them into 2 separate lists you can do something like this:

```
 var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
 parameters.Add("@myParam1", myParam1);
 parameters.Add("@myParam2", myParam2);

 string myQuery = "Your query here";
 var yourFirstList = new List<YourListType>();
 var yourSecondList = new List<YourSecondListType>();

 using (var multi = db.QueryMultiple(myQuery, parameters))
 {
     yourFirstList = multi.Read<YourListType>().ToList();
     yourSecondList = multi.Read<YourSecondList>().ToList();
 }
```

You have to make sure you know the order in which your result sets are coming back to be able to do this i.e. your first list is the first one and the second list is your second list type.